# Does anyone else have lots of duplicate man pages?

Tags: terminal, command-line, performance, homebrew

For example, for the `read` man page, I have a single one for `read(2)`, two of the same for `read(1)` and two of the same for `read(n)`. This has led to some performance and timing issues. I believe it has to do with dependency-management by homebrew, but I am not sure. For example, running

```
$ time man -k ^
makewhatis: /Library/TeX/texbin/man: Not a directory
DeRez(1)                 - decompiles resources (DEPRECATED)
... tens of lines of output
git-branch(1)            - List, create, or delete branches
man -k ^  0.43s user 1.27s system 37% cpu 4.511 total
```

which does not seem normal. Anyone else?

Comment: Do you have MANPATH set? If so. will you edit your post with its value, and what are the results of the command- `manpath` .

Comment: MANPATH is not set. Results of command: `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/share/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man:/Library/TeX/texbin/man:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man:/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/man`. So it seems that the non-directory is on there.

Comment: What kind of performance and timing issues do you face?

Comment: `man -k ^` searches through all man pages, so it has to open over 3000 text files which will take some time. `grep . /usr/share/man/*/*` probably takes a comparable long time.

Comment: I believe it was just an unusual optimization by emacs @nohillside. It was running `man -k ^` as an "auto-complete" feature when I type `M-x man <RET> 2 ` (for getting a specific numbered man page), so I gave it advice to turn it off.

Comment: Regardless of that, there is still the problem of duplicate man pages, which means that I do have some software bloat, though I am not sure how to manage or get to the bottom of it without completely wiping and re-doing my system, and paying more attention in the future.

Comment: @user129393192 Why do a few man pages mean you have "software bloat"?  What problem do you think you're trying to solve?

Comment: If multiple were installed, it likely means that there's multiple installations of the same thing. Also, it's annoying to sift through all of them when I do `man -a read` for example.

Answer (score 1):

They're not duplicates.  Their existence is not leading to any performance or timing issues.  Nor does it have anything to do with dependency management by Homebrew.

They are from different sections of the manual.  The manual sections are defined as:

```
   1      User Commands
   2      System Calls
   3      C Library Functions
   4      Devices and Special Files
   5      File Formats and Conventions
   6      Games et. Al.
   7      Miscellanea
   8      System Administration tools and Deamons
```

So the man page for `read(1)` is for the command-line `read` command.  The man page for `read(2)` is the `read` system call.  The man page for `read(n)` is from TCL.

Comment: What I mean is I have duplicate `read(1)` and duplicate `read(n)`. As I have 2 of the first and 2 of the last ... I thought that was clear from my question,

Comment: I can clearly see this when in emacs, using `man-mode` to scroll through them.

Comment: Having two man pages is not a problem.  All it means is that in the path that `man` constructed, there are two (or more) of an entry, probably provided by different software installs.  They don't cause any slowdowns, they don't take up enough space to matter.

Comment: Well, here is some additional output: `% time man -k ^ | wc 
   12434  101864  923700
man -k ^  0.67s user 1.40s system 103% cpu 1.991 total` so I feel like it is at least some sort of problem ... speaking to others, that takes about 0.1s on their system. I am not sure why the total time is nearly 2s when the user and sys time is .03s

Comment: The man page for `man` tells you how to configure it.  You can also drop path specificatioins as detailed in the man page for `path_helper`.

Comment: How is this a Linux/macOS problem?

Comment: It isn't.  `man_db.conf` is Linux.  I shouldn't have said it and I deleted it.

Comment: Got it. So your advice is to look into what's going on in `MANPATH`? I just configured it a bit and will look into manually adding and dropping paths, but I don't see how that really explains why `man -k ^` would be so slow.

Comment: My "advice" is that you don't have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to my surprise, I do have the same issue. Briefly looking into the issue-

```
[crystalwell:fd0] $ man -k tcsh
tcsh(1)                  - C shell with file name completion and command line editing
tcsh(1)                  - C shell with file name completion and command line editing
```

Two directories mirror each other-

`/usr/share/man/man1`

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/share/man/man1`

Thinking about this I realize that `makewhatis` can't write its database to a readonly filesystem. In fact, `makewhatis` seems to be disabled on my system.